# Sqlalchemy: OperationalError with pycharm but not at command line

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pycharm

[image]I'm working with scrapy and have had a functioning pipeline which uses sql-alchemy to insert records into a sqllite db. This was working but then I added 2 new fields: name and address. Now I'm getting:

```
2016-06-14 10:12:23 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'account': u'X6',
 'address': u' the address',
 'name': u'my name'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\envs\r2\tutorial\tutorial\pipelines.py", line 54, in process_item
    self.connection.execute(ins_query)
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table accounts has no column named name [SQL: u'INSERT INTO accounts (account, name, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'X6', u' my name', u' the address')]
```

Here's the pipeline code:

```
class MYPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        _engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")
        _connection = _engine.connect()
        _metadata = MetaData()
        _stack_items = Table("accounts", _metadata,
                             Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                             Column("account", Text),
                             Column("name", Text),
                             Column("address", Text))
        _metadata.create_all(_engine)
        self.connection = _connection
        self.stack_items = _stack_items

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        is_valid = True
        for data in item:
            if not data:
                is_valid = False
                raise DropItem("Missing %s!" % data)
        if is_valid:
            ins_query = self.stack_items.insert().values(
                account=item["account"],
                name=item["name"],
                address=item["address"])
            self.connection.execute(ins_query)
        return item
```

Whats weird is that if I run this using :

```
scrapy crawl myspider
```

using GIT-Bash (I'm using win7) this works normally. However with pycharm I get the errors above.

for pycharm the run config is in the screenshot, and man.py:

```
from scrapy import cmdline    
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl myspider".split())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the working directory set to?

Comment: C:\envs\r2\tutorial\tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're running with two different working directories. Try configuring PyCharm with the working directory you're using on the command line. Alternatively, specify an absolute path for the SQLAlchemy URL.

Comment: I changed the working directory to C:\envs\r2\tutorial and it started working!